# Exctracting values and their coordinates from a raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: raster, layers, coordinates, values

I would like to extract the pixel value and coordinates of each of them from a ndvi raster layer. I don't have a point layer from where I can extract those values, as I read in other posts.
Specifically, in this experiment I have a ndvi image from a vineyard field and I want to discretize the different treatments that we applied on this field. To do so, int he first place I want to get the pixel values and their coordinates (E,N), not the whole layer but from some parts that I selected by creating a polygon.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, which software are you using?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I am using QGIS.

Comment: Up till now I have individuated my wine rows by drawing a polygoin and then I extract my raster layer by mask. Here si where I want to extract pixel values and their respective coordinates but I don't know how. I was looking for information but just found out examples with points sampling. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, maybe you could reclassify your raster to create some classes and then extract the polygon's coordinates for each class?

Comment: Thanks. But is it not possible to extract pixel value and their respective coordinates?

Comment: For each pixel?? What's the size of this raster?

Comment: Yes, for the pixels inside of my polygon layer, which correspond to one vine row Or I was thinking that another possibility is to do a random sampling points and extract the values from those points. Could be feasible like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a polygon of interest you can:
1. Create a grid of points inside your polygon by using **Regular Points** from your toolbox and setting the **input extent** to your polygon's extent and the point spacing as you wish.
2. Take the values from your raster by using the **Sample raster values** with input point layer your regular points layer.
3. Add geometry columns to your point layer by using **Add geometry attributes**.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to try this!